# How to get tag's attribute using PHP simple HTML DOM parser

Tags: php, html, curl

I am using the [PHP Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to scrap website data, but unfortunately not able to extract the data i want to. I have also tried to google and look in the documentation but could not solve the issue. The code structure of what i am trying to scrap is something like this.

```
<div id="section1">
   <h1>Some content</h1>
   <p>Some content</p>
   ............
    <<Not fixed number of element>>
   ............
   <script> <<Some script>></script>
   <video>
     <source src="www.exmple.com/34/exmple.mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

I tried with JavaScript and i could do the same like this

```
document.getElementById("section1").getElementsByTagName("source")[0].getAttribute("src");
```

But when i tried with PHP Dom parser i m not getting any data.
Here is how my code looks likes

```
require ''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../lib/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';

 $html_content = get($url); //This is cURL function to get website content.
 $obj_content = str_get_html($html_content);
 $linkURL = $obj_content->getElementById('section1')->find('source',0)->getAttribute('src');
var_dump($linkURL);
```

This results in an empty string. I also tried changing to code a bit here and there but none of those works every time came blank. But if i `var dump $obj_content` i get lot of dom element

I tried to follow these posts from stackoverflow which are similar to mine , but these did not help me.

1. [How do I get the HTML code of a web page in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819182/how-do-i-get-the-html-code-of-a-web-page-in-php)
2. [PHP Simple HTML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200304/php-simple-html-dom)
3. [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Call to a member function children() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147044/php-simple-html-dom-parser-call-to-a-member-function-children-on-a-non-object)
4. And their manual http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Can anyone please help me

Thank you

Comment: Is that part of the HTML added dynamically after page load?

Comment: No the page load once. There is no dynamically adding after that

Comment: So if you var_dump whatever is returned from your cURL request, do you see this source tag with a value in the src attribute?

Comment: if i var_dump the curl response i see the complete page

Comment: OK then - look at the HTML from the var_dump, find the #section1 > source[0] path, and see if there's a value in the src attribute.

Comment: Can you share the URL your trying with?

Comment: This works: `$dom->getElementById('section1')->find('video', 0)->find('source', 0)->getAttribute('src');`  The key is to find the parent `<video>` element and then look at the child `<source>` elements to extract the `src` attribute value.

Comment: @WillardSolutions, you were correct. The source file url that i am trying to fetch is actually getting injected by the JS script that is above video tag. 
Extracting content of the script tag and striping the content i took out the url i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet is fine as it is. Problem was that the URL that I was targeting was not there at the time of page load. It was added by the `<script>` tag after page being loaded.

Thank you @WillardSolutions